# JQuery validation is not working with value comparision

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using Jquery validation in form fields. But I comapre a value between a range, the validation got failed in a specific case.

My HTML template is:

```
< input type="text" id="userAge" name="userAge" cssClass="validate[custome[ageValidator]]">
```

My JQuery Validation snippet is:

```
"ageValidator":{ "func": function (field) { if (field.val() >= $(.'minAge').val() && field.val() <= $(.'maxAge').val()) { return true; else { return false; } }
```

Now if min age is 55 and max age is 75 then the validation failing if the input age is 7 and if max age is 65 and min age is 55 then validation failing when you put input age as 6

Comment: Could if be that the else is inside the if?

Comment: No it is like this:
if (field.val() >= $(.'minAge').val() && field.val() <= $(.'maxAge').val()) { return true; } else { return false; }

Validation works when
a. min value is 55 and maz value is 65 and you try to input 4 or 5 or 7. But once you enter 6 it got failed 
b. min value is 55 and maz value is 75 and you try to input 4 or 5 or 6. But once you enter 7 it got failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting the values to integer by using **+** shorthand, just like following

`"ageValidator":{ "func": function (field) { if (+field.val() >= +$(.'minAge').val() && +field.val() <= +$(.'maxAge').val()) { return true; else { return false; } }`